# Image Registration using orb - warped image not changing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, orb, image-registration

I'm trying to register 2 similar images; however I end up with the exact reference picture after executing my code.

My main aim from registering those 2 pictures is to find the differences, any ideas how can I obtain the difference?

```
orb= cv.ORB_create(1000)
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(grey, None)
kp2, dess2 = orb.detectAndCompute(greyy, None)  
matcher = cv.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv.DescriptorMatcher_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)

matches = matcher.match(des1, des2, None)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x:x.distance)

points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

for i, match in enumerate(matches):
    points1[i, :] = kp1[match.queryIdx].pt
    points2[i, :] = kp2[match.trainIdx].pt

h, mask= cv.findHomography(points1, points2, cv.RANSAC)

regimg = cv.warpPerspective(img1, h, (width,height))
cv.imshow('registered', regimg)
```

As requested in the comments: [Matched images using orb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5qEz.jpg)

Comment: What do your images look like? Can you share them too?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk i've posted what i get after using orb, the registered image just looks like the one on left which is the reference, i just want to compute the differences between them.

Comment: You have so many incorrect matches. You should check the valid matches, obtained by findhomography to see how they effect the registration.